# Why ~/.vimrc is not working for vim on ubuntu server

Tags: vim, ubuntu-server

I installed ubuntu server on vmware player. I want to use vim, so I put `.vimrc` file under my home directory.

But when I open `vim`, `vim` is **not** using the configuration from the file `~/.vimrc`.

If I do it the same way on a ubuntu desktop virtual machine, everything works fine.

> What did I do wrong in the server environment? What else should I do?

Comment: What is the full output of `vim --version`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to tell if your .vimrc is running at all, put

```
echom ".vimrc message 1"
```

On the first line of ~/.vimrc

Then launch `vim` and type

```
:messages
```

in regular mode. If you see ".vimrc message 1", you know that the .vimrc is at least being read ... it may be stopping before it does anything useful, but at least vim is picking it up.

I would also try `which vim` to see which program is being called when you type `vim`.

Comment: Far easier to just see which scripts where sources via `:scriptnames`

Answer (score 0):

You can capture a full log of a Vim session with `vim -V20vimlog`. After quitting Vim, examine the `vimlog` log file. It will show where Vim searched.

Does Vim correctly detect your home directory? `:echo $HOME` will tell you.

Also, read `:help .vimrc` for details on the resolution and locations of `.vimrc`.